# Current time in an image?

Tags: php, image, time

I would like to find an image (Any type: png gif jpg etc) that shows current time (UTC) and updates every minute. I have looked everywhere and cannot find one. This will be used in a software called TeamSpeak, it doesn't allow embedding of any HTML code only images. I have a server I can host a php script necessary to make the image.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy enough to do with GD:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

Comment: +1 the image won't be "real time" as he wants it, but it does the job

Comment: @Joseph, How not?  All you have to do is generate the image on the fly when the script is hit.

Comment: the op said *"I would like to find an image (Any type: png gif jpg etc) that shows current time (UTC) and updates **every minute**."* and *"TeamSpeak, it doesn't allow embedding of any HTML code only images"*. so how would that be?

Comment: @Joseph, My read is that he wants an image that is updated every minute.  Generating the image upon request makes that happen.